# Web scraper web app using Django on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am creating web app that does two tasks:

1. Data visualization on dashboard for user (web page)
2. Scraping for data periodically (like 3 times a day for everyday)

I have created the dashboard and deployed it on Heroku. For database, I am using postgres inside Heroku.

My question is how should I structure the django project?

Do you recommend to split the app into two projects?
Or build the scraper in django? If this is the case, is it possible to have the scraper run all the time continuously along with the dashboard inside Heroku?

Thanks